# How to ping an IP address in another domain?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, ip, ping

I am using Windows 7 Professional.

There is first computer named **hrcomp1** whose IP address is **192.168.36.100** and it is in domain **hrdomain.local**.

There is second computer named **bencomp1** whose IP address is **192.168.58.214** and it is in domain **bendomain.local**.

I am logged into second computer **bencomp1** and I want to ping the first computer **hrcomp1**.

I can ping the first computer by name by typing in `ping hrcomp1.hrdomain.local` and it work perfect.

But how can I ping the first computer by its IP address? I type in `ping 192.168.36.100.hrdomain.local` but I get this error message:

> Ping request could not find host 192.168.36.100.hrdomain.local. Please check the  name
>   and try again.

How can I do that?

Comment: Don't put the domain on it, just ping the address.

Comment: IP addresses *do not belong* to a domain. They're what you get *after* letting DNS do the "domain → address" translation.  So it does not make any sense to glue the domain name to an address – just use one or the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confused about a couple of things. Network addresses, like IP addresses, are simply binary numbers. IPv4 addresses are written in the dotted-decimal notation to make them easier to read, but they get converted to binary for use. DNS takes it one step further, and it uses words to represent an IP address, but it needs a server to convert from the word to a binary number.

You are trying to mix the two different methods.

Simply `ping 192.168.36.100` without the domain attached.